# Gradle 7.0 Lint Error when using local custom view library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint, gradlew

I am using a custom view library and add it as one of the project's module. Everything works fine and it is running, however when I tried to run `gradlew lint` the it fails with the message

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Projects\Android\Personal Product\App\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:62 Error: Class referenced in the layout file, com.library.custom.view, was not found in the project or the libraries [MissingClass]
        <com.library.custom.view
```

The lint until now seems not able to properly recognize a local library. Is there any fix on this without using

```
android {
               lintOptions {
                   abortOnError false
               }
           }
```